# I want to move all my products and their attributes to my new store

Tags: product, export, importexport, programmatically, ee-1.13

What is the best way to accomplish this? Please don't just say "magmi".

Additionally, my dataflow profiles do not work on my local/vagrant build. It just keeps timing out.

Is there a way to do it through a PHP script to export to CSV file or through MySQL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will help you to export all product to csv file. The file will be generated in `var/inportexport` folder.

```
$data=array(); 
$data['entity'] = 'catalog_product';  
$data['file_format'] = 'csv';  
$data['form_key'] = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();  
$data['export_filter'] = array();  
$model = Mage::getModel('importexport/export');     
$model->setData($data);

$model->export();  
$model->getContentType();
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution to my thread. What about attributes, will this include them as well?

Comment: ya. you use this script. it include all the attribute.

Comment: voted up my answer if you satisfy with my answer.

Comment: It just timed out on my dev environment.

Comment: how many product in yout store?

Comment: 10k or more @jigs parmar

Comment: $data['export_filter']=array(); in this line you specify condition to select some of the product and try the entire code and check the csv.